# gfortran flags for most high performing production code

Tags: gfortran, compiler-flags

Would you please suggest GNU Fortran compiler `gfortran` flags for the most high performing production code? Currently I'm using `gfortran -O3`. The code will be run on 64-bit Intel platforms.

Answer (score 4):

This might be an extended comment rather than an answer, but here goes anyway.

The kind folk who write `gfortran`, and the kind folk who write other compilers all of which offer similar facilities, have provided optimisation flags such as `-O2` and `-O3` for programmers who don't have the time or inclination to find out what the best combination of compiler flags for their code on their platform might be.  As you will have learnt from your own research those flags are translated into a bunch of other, more narrowly focused, flags.

You may, or may not, already be familiar with the, initially surprising, case of a code which runs faster with `-O2` than with `-O3`.  When you first encounter this you will spend time with the individual optimisation flags, turning them on and off, combining them in different ways, until you develop an understanding of which ones work for your code, and which ones don't.  Either that or you give up in frustration and do something else with your time.

There is no silver bullet for optimising all codes for all platforms.  It's hard work, and only you can decide if it's worth while to spend, say, two weeks to squeeze 5% speed-up out of a program.  And the only way to develop a good sense of when the effort is likely to be rewarding is to develop an intimate familiarity with the individual optimisation options that your compiler offers through extensive practice and investigation.

And then you change compilers, or the compiler-writers introduce new or enhanced features, and your quest begins again, though not from the beginning.

Finally, with `gfortran` you could try `-Ofast`.